# Проверка нескольких bool в одном условии

Tags: c++, if, логические-выражения

Как я могу сократить данную строку? C++

```
if (!damaged[0] && !damaged[1] && !damaged[2] && !damaged[3] && !damaged[4] && !damaged[5] && !damaged[6])
```

Comment: Что такое `damaged`? Массив? В нем ровно 7 элементов?

Comment: Какой тип имеет damage?

Comment: В смысле "сократить"? Даже ценой потери эффективности?

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно написал и не ошибся :), то

```
if (all_of(damaged,damaged+7,[](auto x)->bool{return !x;})) 

if (!any_of(damaged,damaged+7,[](auto x)->bool{return x;}))

if (accumulate(damaged,damaged+7,true,[](auto x, auto y) { return x && !y; }))
```

Comment: Забыли `std::none_of` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (std::find(damaged, damaged + 7, false) < damaged + 7)
   ...

if (std::count(damaged, damaged + 7, false) == 7)
   ...
```

Второй вариант - неразумен, ибо подавляет сокращенное вычисление.

Comment: А если там `int damaged[7]`? `false` отработает верно, не будет проблемм?